# Renaming files with numbered 0-padding names while leaving pre-renamed ones alone

Tags: bash

I have several .jpg files in serveral folders about 20K actually. The filename are different like 123.jpg, abc.jpg, ab12.jpg. What is need is to rename all those files using bash script with leading 0 pattern.

I had used one code down below and while I do this the everytime I add new files the previous files get renamed again. Could anyone help me out from this situation and this would be really help full. I have searched entire web for this and not find one :(

```
#!/bin/bash
num=0
for i in *.jpg
do
    a=`printf "%05d" $num`
    mv "$i" "filename_$a.jpg"
    let "num = $(($num + 1))"
done
```

---

To provide a concrete example of the problem, consider:

```
touch foo.jpg bar.jpg baz.jpg
```

The first time this script is run, `bar.jpg` is renamed to `filename_00000.jpg`; `baz.jpg` is renamed to `filename_00001.jpg`; `foo.jpg` is renamed to `filename_00002.jpg`. This behavior is acceptable.

If someone then runs:

```
touch a.jpg
```

...and runs the script again, then it renames `a.jpg` to `filename_00000.jpg`, renames `filename_00000.jpg` (now `a.jpg`, as the old version got overwritten!) to `filename_00001.jpg`, renames `filename_00001.jpg` to `filename_00002.jpg`, etc.

How can I make the program leave the files already matching `filename_#####.jpg` alone, and rename new files to have numbers after the last one that already exists?

Comment: Sorry I have mentioned .png in the script actually its .jpg.

Comment: Your code and your question don't quite correspond.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you I'm new to this that  y I came here for help.

Comment: @danishjoseph : What is a *leading zero pattern*? If you would really run the **exact** code which you posted, I would expect that the JPG files "disappear" in the sense that you would end up with a single file named `filename_.jpg`. If you ask questions, please publish the code, which you have right now, in unmodified form. Otherwise, there is nothing we could discuss here.

Comment: I have modified the code but the actual output that I need to obtain is like 

123.jpg. ---  filename_0123.jpg
And.jpg ----  filename_0124.jpg

Have to get those files in an order form through the script and I want it to add as an cron job as if I add new files it will be automatically named according to that name convention.

Comment: Iam keeping this script in a folder which I would have all the files mentioned above like 123.jpg, And.jpg, picture.jpg etc and I need to get it ordered.

Comment: `0124` is going to be treated as octal by bash. We already have answered questions in the knowledgebase about how to force parse as decimal. BTW, `let` is ancient pre-POSIX syntax and should basically never be used in modern scripts.

Comment: You will face the same issue of files getting new names when you overflow past file 99,999 and have to use `%06d` for formatting...

Comment: What happens if you delete files 00001 through 00080? Do the slots ever get reclaimed?

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s extglob  # enable extended globbing -- regex-like syntax
prefix="filename_"

# Find the largest-numbered file previously renamed
num=0                                     # initialize counter to 0
for f in "$prefix"+([[:digit:]]).jpg; do  # Iterate only over names w/ prefix/suffix
  f=${f#"$prefix"}                        # strip the prefix
  f=${f%.jpg}                             # strip the suffix
  if (( 10#$f > num )); then              # force base-10 evaluation
    num=$(( 10#$f ))
  fi
done

# Second pass: Iterate over *all* names, and rename the ones that don't match the pattern
for i in *.jpg; do
  [[ $i = "$prefix"+([[:digit:]]).jpg ]] && continue # Skip files already matching pattern
  printf -v a '%05d' "$num"                          # More efficient than subshell use
  until mv -n -- "$i" "$prefix$a.jpg"; do            # "--" forces parse of "$i" as name
    [[ -e "$i" ]] || break                           # abort if source file disappeared
    num=$((num + 1))                                 # if we couldn't rename, increment num
    printf -v a '%05d' "$num"                        # ...and try again with the next name
  done
  num=$((num + 1))                                   # modern POSIX math syntax
done
```

Note the use of `mv -n` to prevent overwrites -- that way two copies of this script running at the same time won't overwrite each others' files.

Comment: I think it would be possible to avoid iterating over the already renamed files by using `find . -mindepth 1 -not -name 'filename_*.jpg' -print0` and `read -d ''`, wouldn't it? Not sure how much of an improvement it would be though.

Comment: You need to iterate over the already-renamed files no matter what to find the largest number. Could do just one pass and *either* increment the number or append to a list to process later, I suppose.

Comment: Hmm I meant avoid the iteration and having to `continue` in the second loop, not in the first one

Comment: Sure -- you can do that, but it's still iterating over the full list of names at the filesystem level; it's just a question of whether it's C inside the `find` command or your shell script doing it; *if* `find` is faster in some scenarios (which it could not be if the shell `read` is too expensive), then whether we're in one of those scenarios depends on whether there are enough files to overcome its startup costs.

Comment: Huuu yeah, I hadn't considered that. Thanks for bearing with me ! :)